# Printing List giving wrong size

Tags: scala, arraylist

Upon receiving employeeJobDataList data, I have created

```
var resultList: List[List[AnytimePayEmployeeJobData]] = new ArrayList[List[AnytimePayEmployeeJobData]]
```

where I am adding List of data having `BATCH_THRESHOLD = 25`

Here is the code snippet:

```
val upsertsFailedBatches: List[FailedBatch] = new ArrayList[FailedBatch]
val upsertsEmployeeJobDataList: List[AnytimePayEmployeeJobData] = new ArrayList[AnytimePayEmployeeJobData]
var resultList: List[List[AnytimePayEmployeeJobData]] = new ArrayList[List[AnytimePayEmployeeJobData]]

for (i <- 0 until employeeJobDataList.size()) {
  upsertsEmployeeJobDataList.add(employeeJobDataList.get(i))
  if (upsertsEmployeeJobDataList.size() == BATCH_THRESHOLD) {
    resultList.add(upsertsEmployeeJobDataList)
    upsertsEmployeeJobDataList.clear()
  }
}
 if (upsertsEmployeeJobDataList.size() > 0) {
  resultList.add(upsertsEmployeeJobDataList)
}
```

Although, I am adding List of 25 data in resultList but while checking size using print statement it is showing me 4
Here is the output: batch size: 4

```
 for (i <- 0 until resultList.size()){
  println("batch size: "+ resultList.get(i).size())
}
```

Comment: Is this scala? or Java. How both ?

Comment: this is a scala code

Comment: What are the contents of `employeeJobDataList`? Also as a general comment this is rather poor scala code containing a lot of mutable state.

Comment: @RonySingh Then please remove java tag

Comment: Any reason why this uses Java's collections instead of Scala ones? This is literally `upsertsFailedBatches.grouped(BATCH_THRESHOLD).toList` one liner

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason why this doesn't work is that you use mutable collection.

```
for (i <- 0 until employeeJobDataList.size()) {
  upsertsEmployeeJobDataList.add(employeeJobDataList.get(i))
  if (upsertsEmployeeJobDataList.size() == BATCH_THRESHOLD) {
    resultList.add(upsertsEmployeeJobDataList)
    upsertsEmployeeJobDataList.clear()
  }
}
```

When one batch is filled you:

- add a reference of a collection to another collection
- instead of creating a new collection for next batch, you remove all elements of it
  and start adding them anew

As a result you have a collection where one and the same list if repeated `size() / BATCH_THRESHOLD` times and its content is the last `size() % BATCH_THRESHOLD` items.

Instead of `clear` you should have created a new collection... but this whole code can be just replaced by one liner if you use Scala collections instead:

```
upsertsFailedBatches.grouped(BATCH_THRESHOLD).toList
```